# How to get device token of device in Unity 5?

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, unityscript, devicetoken

I am tring to get device token and I dont want to use Update function.

Right now I am using following function:

```
if (!tokenSent) {
    token =UnityEngine.iOS.NotificationServices.deviceToken;
    if (token != null) {
        // send token to a provider
        print ("My device Token");
        hexToken= "%" + System.BitConverter.ToString(token).Replace('-', '%');
        tokenSent = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider editing your question to include information about what is wrong with your current code: is `token` simply `null`? Do you get a run time exception? ...

Comment: I am not getting any token.

Comment: Do you call NotificationServices.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes prior to the token request?

Comment: yes, in the Start function.